# open graph image not working in hotmail

Tags: facebook-opengraph, hotmail

I got these meta tags the head of my sites, but `hotmail` shows no image when calling the url.

Any idea to solve this?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Customer title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Customer description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://customerurl.nl/images/ogimage.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://customerurl.nl/" />
```

The og-tool of Facebook shows the right image, but shows also a warning I don't understand.

> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

But it is explicit present, not just a few hours, a few months.

Comment: meta tag is present: <meta property="og:image" content="http://customerurl.nl/images/ogimage.png" />

Comment: Hey, I'm curious if you resolved this? I'm seeing the same issue. Moreover hotmail parser seems to be not using other meta tags, like `og:description`. It's almost like it scrapes them from other pages on the same domain.

Comment: No, not yet unfortunately. Maybe someone can report this to Microsoft.

Comment: I might be mistaking but my assumption so far is that Outlook Mail parser might be getting the `og` info from what they scraped via Bing, which **is very lame** if it's true. [[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/e6a26d9e-258b-4de6-b47d-61156951d6b9/outlook-web-access-url-preview-pane-can-i-control-which-image-gets-selected-from-the-site-?forum=outlookdev)]. It seems like Skype always works this way.